# What Wordpress file usually contains the code when I display all posts in a category?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a Wordpress website, and I have one of my main blog links going to the URL of the category that displays all the blog posts. On that page shows the date, the featured image, and the first 50 or so words of the post followed by "Read more"

I want to change the number of first words that it shows on the category page. For example, I want it to show the first 100 words instead of the first 50. Which PHP page would I need to edit to do this? And what is the code in the page?

Answer (score 0):

category.php shows On single category page. 
but content of post showing from content.php.

Some staring words of post showing from the_excerpt() function.

You want to showing first 100 words.
So you need to increase the limit of this function of showing starting words.
And for this you will use function.php